# Smooth pasting conditions for optimal investment with transactions costs

Tags: transaction-costs

I'm reading [this paper](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/lpederse/courses/LAP/papers/TransactionCosts/Dumas91.pdf) relating to optimal investment with transaction costs where some value function $F(x)$ is optimized. At some boundary $x=u$ it will be optimal to pay a proportional cost $C$ which gives the boundary condition

\begin{equation}
F'(u) = -C
\end{equation}

The author argues that optimality also implies a boundary condition for the second derivative

\begin{equation}
F''(u) = 0
\end{equation}

but I'm struggling to understand why this is the case. Any hints that will help me understand the intuition behind this condition?

Comment: Does $C$ depend on $u$?

Comment: $C>0$ is just some constant.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't the second equation follow from $F'$ being constant?

Comment: It's only constant at $x=u$. Note that $x$ is the variable and $x=u$ is the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

I think that they are saying that, at *special* point $u$, we have:

$$ F'(u) = -\rho. $$

Also, that in a neighborhood from the left, we have:

$$ F'(u- dU) = -\rho $$

for any small positive $dU$.

Then, with Taylor on the left:

$$ F'(u) - F''(u)dU = - \rho $$

Hence: $$ F''(u) = 0 $$

Basically, if the first derivative of a function is constant in a neighborhood of a point, then its second derivative must be null at that point.

Comment: Why is $F'(u- dU) = -\rho $ true?

Comment: Equation (10) it seems. Setting $v$ to $u-dU$.